# I want to redirect the output of ls to a file AND also append a constant string to each file that is listed in the output file

Tags: bash, file, redirect, ls

I want to redirect the output of ls to a file, but also append a string to each entry that is listed by ls.  For example:

Suppose there are 3 files in my current director, a.txt, b.txt and c.txt.

If I do 
    ls > output.txt

This will put the directory listing  into the file output.txt which will have (approximately)

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

Now I want to append the letter hello in front of each file name so the file output.txt looks like this:

```
hello a.txt
hello b.txt
hello c.txt
```

How do I do this???

Comment: `ls | sed 's/^/Hello /'` ,try reading about `find` and replace `ls` with `find`

Comment: `for i in *;do echo "hello $i";done`

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Hi @PS, adding sed works perfectly, thank you so much !!

Comment: Yet another option: `printf 'hello %s\n' *`

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(find . -type f -name "*.txt"); do 
  echo "hello $(basename $file)"; 
done
```

Use `find` to find each file in the current dir with extension of `.txt`, then `echo` hello before the filename. Use `basename` to get just the filename, else it'll display like `./a.txt`

If you *only* want to search in the current dir, and not subdirs, then add `-depth 1` to the `find` command.

**Update:** In response to the comment: Most Bash constructs can be made into one-liners by using semicolons appropriately, so you could easily do:

```
for file in $(find . -type f -name "*.txt"); do echo "hello $(basename $file)"; done
```

Comment: Hi zwbetz, I was looking for a command line solution so yours probably works but it's not applicable to me, thank you